# How to Deploy live JavaScript to all users at once

Tags: javascript, php, apache2

Basically I need to parse JavaScript to a live server to everyuser who is currently logged in at the sametime. [For live notifications and other valuations]

I have already tried

> php 
>   while(loop)......
>   **@ this point i didn't close or terminate or break the while loop at the end but rather setinterval in javascript to keep posting synchronous requests**

It actually worked but I realized the the  infinite loop performs over 10000 requests to my server in just30 minutes and also freezes the client's  interface.

How can I achieve that...
Thanks n advance

Comment: Please have a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Comment: Can't you just decrease the interval at which you're sending requests to the server.... It's a little bit unclear what you're trying to do...

Comment: Yes I thought of that but I reduces live ability I need. I reduced the interval to the lowest but still the client was not so effective n that also make it more hard to perform live updates

Comment: Yeah I had to us php to make the site look like a stateful connection.  Just had to implement commet ajax